# Possible to render a partial from a link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to create a fancy login form for my webapp in Ruby On Rails using Twitter-Bootstraps modal feature.

Here' s my form currently.

**_login_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal hide" id="loginModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Sign in</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name),:html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
            <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
            <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn' %>
        <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's my Coffescript.

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $('#login').modal('show')
```

Is there anyway to call the form from a partial?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Ajax: your link would trigger an Ajax call. The response would be the modal with the login form, and then you'd have to append the response HTML to you document and display the modal.

Otherwise you can simply load the modal with your page, which would be faster for the user, since he won't have to wait for the Ajax response.

Comment: Thanks! Ive never worked with AJAX much before. Have you got any suggested reading material?

Comment: I have nothing in mind right now, but you can check in Nettuts, they usually provide great and simple tutorials.